# best way to send data from android->server->another android in realtime

Tags: android, django, rest, sockets, http

I am currently doing a project that sends sensor data from Arduino to Android(patient's app) then sends those data from android to server, then sends them to another Android(guardian's app). We are using Django for backend.

Thus, I am thinking 2 ways to send Data in real-time(every one second).

1.Using Http Rest Api(update MySQL every second from patient's android, and get data from MySQL every second from guardian's android).

2.Django channels which is good for chatting application, and our project seems pretty similar.

I have experienced HTTP REST API before, but I am new to socket programming.
Which is better way? HTTP rest API vs Django channels?

Comment: I think `Long Polling` would be a solution or even better `Web Sockets`. Also there is `Firebase`.

Comment: @Naveen Niraula what is difference between web sockets and just tcp sockets? is web sockets better?

Comment: In a broad sense `TCP sockets` is just `TCP` but `Web Sockets` is something like `HTTP ( which is based on TCP )`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) an option for you? You wouldn't have to deal with any server development.

Comment: I like firebase a lot, but we are trying to do and learn some server development in this project.. so firebase is not our option,,,